# Tomcat creates new threads instead of using free threads (in waiting state)

Tags: java, tomcat, jira

I have application (Jira 8.13) deployed on Apache Tomcat/8.5.60 . Sometimes, random nodes of cluster start creating new http threads instead of reusing existing threads in WAITING state. Eventually tomcat reaches http thread limit and stop accepting new requests, but other part of application works. No signs of anomalies in tomcat or app logs. Only Tomcat restart helps. Thread dump of these threads is similar

```java
http-nio-8080-exec-2618 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215) java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078) java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467) org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.poll(TaskQueue.java:90) org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.poll(TaskQueue.java:33) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

As I understand, this dump is pretty normal for http thread which is waiting for work. Connector config

```xml
<Connector port="8080" relaxedPathChars="[]|" relaxedQueryChars="[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;"
    maxThreads="200" minSpareThreads="25" enableLookups="false"
    maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" protocol="HTTP/1.1" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" redirectPort="8443"
    acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="120000" disableUploadTimeout="true" bindOnInit="false"
    secure="true" scheme="https" proxyName="*" proxyPort="443" keyAlias="jira" keystoreFile="/* /jira.jks" keystorePass="*" keystoreType="JKS"/>
```

What could be the cause of tomcat creating new threads instead of using existing free threads(in waiting state) or maybe there is a way to debug such behavior? As workaround I think of configuring Executor and set `maxIdleTime` to some reasonable value.

Comment: How do you know its not accepting new connections? When users access that page what happens exactly? Ignoring the thread dump what happens that tells you something isn't working?

Comment: port 8080 of tomcat becomes unresponsive, so user cant acces pages via browser, but backend of app continues to work